# Setting ICDBurn dialog to modal or always-on-top

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I have a WPF application using the ICDBurn interface to burn some data to a disk. 
After calling `ICDBurn::Burn` a dialog is shown and the user should not be able to continue working with the application until this dialog is handled, which is not the default behaviour.
I tried passing both `IntPtr.Zero` as well as the applications main window handle as a parent to `ICDBurn::Burn`, but the result was the same.

So I want this dialog to be modal, but I would settle for setting this dialog to always on top as well.

As a first step, I figured I would need a handle to the dialog's window. I tried `EnumChildWindows` but did not find the dialog there. 
How can I set this dialog to modal?

Edit:
based on the comment from IInspectable, I maybe passed the wrong window handle to Burn. I am using `new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle` and I think I use no other windows in the application.

Comment: *"the result was the same"* - What *is* the observed behavior?

Comment: I get a dialog that I can send to the background by clicking on the main application window.

Comment: In that case you are passing the wrong window handle into `ICDBurn::Burn`. Had you passed the correct window handle, the dialog would always be in front of the owning window (even though not necessarily modal). I don't know which window handle to pass for a WPF application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, WPF...

To get ICDBurn::Burn to correctly open as a modal dialog, it has to be called on the UI Thread (using `Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher`).